# System.currentTimeMillis() not displaying time in UTC , instead displaying current timezone time

Tags: java

I have a requirement of getting UTC time , hence in many places iam using below code for calcualting utc time.

```
System.currentTimeMillis() ;
```

Iam in IST - (GMT+5:30) , System.currentTimeMillis() - should display UTC time (IST-5:30) , instead it is taking current time (GMT+5:30). 
I donot want to use the Apache of joda date and time api. i want to use the Java api itslef. Help me in resolve my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` just returns a `long` - that's not in *any* sort of date format.

If you're actually using:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(date);
```

then you're just seeing the result of `Date.toString()`, which always uses the system default time zone.

Use `DateFormat` (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`) to specify the calendar system (typically Gregorian), time zone and format you want to use. For example:

```
Date date = ...;
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                                         Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

String result = format.format(date);
```

As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend abstracting the idea of "getting the current time" into an interface which you implement in one case using `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or equivalently, just `new Date()`) but implement for *testing* purposes with a value you can set and update at will. Then inject this "clock" interface into anything which needs to access the current date/time. It makes it *much* easier to test time-based components.

(I'd also strongly recommend using Joda Time or the `java.time` package from Java 8 if you possibly can. I know you've said you don't want to, but I suspect that's because you haven't spent as much time swearing at `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` as some of us. Both of those alternatives will lead to *much* cleaner code which is *much* easier to read and reason about. If you're trying to avoid a one-time hit of getting Joda Time into your build process, weigh that against the amount of time you're likely to spend maintaining your code. Or just update to Java 8... Java 7 will be out of free-update support soon anyway...)

Comment: so , i have the following date class code `public static Date getUTCDate(long utcTime) {
  Date localDate = new Date(utcTime);
  String format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat (format);
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  Date utcDate = new Date(sdf.format(localDate));
  return utcDate;
 }`  and my server is in CST timezone , if i call the code 'getUTCDate(System.currentTimeMillis)' will it display the right UTC date or time. advice me in this

Comment: so u mean to say that , If iam in CST , central america , and if i used the system.currentTimeMillis() - will it display the CST long time (UTC-6:00 ) or  UTC long Time (CST+6:00)

Comment: @SrivathsanSrinivasan: Why would you be converting it into a string at all if your method is meant to return a `Date`? Do you understand that a `Date` object has no notion of a time zone? It's *just* a number of milliseconds since the unix epoch. Calling the method above won't *display* anything - it'll create a new `Date`, then format it, then parse it - for no obvious reason.

Comment: the basic idea i have is, by passing the sys.currTimeMillis (Current CST long time) , in to the above method , as u have descibed , will gimme a time in UTC format.

Comment: @SrivathsanSrinivasan: You're mistaken about what everything means. `System.currentTimeMillis()` doesn't return "Current CST long time" - it returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. That isn't in any particular time zone - you'd get the same result everywhere in the world. (If you run it now, you'd get the same result as if I run it now.) Likewise, a `Date` is just a wrapper for a number of days since the unix epoch. If you want an object representing a date/time in a particular time zone, you need `java.util.Calendar`. If you just want it as a string, use `DateFormat`.

Comment: thanks a lot , actually till now , i had a very bad understanding of `System.currentTimeMillis()` , now i ve got it , so another question is , if my server timezone is CST , america , and if i use the below code `Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(date);` in ear deployed in that server , i will be getting the CST current time right , so if i want that time to be in utc , i shld use `dateformat ` api to achieve , as u ve initially posted right????

Comment: @SrivathsanSrinivasan: Yes, exactly. That's *just* a matter of the string representation though. Note that you can just use `new Date()` and that will use `System.currentTimeMillis()` automatically.

Comment: finally i have changed the code , is this the right one , for getting UTC timestamp in long value , PFA code  `public static long getUTCDate(Date localDate) { 
  String format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat (format); 
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
  String strUTCDate =(sdf.format(localDate));
  Date utcDate = new Date(strUTCDate);
  return utcDate.getTime();
  }`  calling method be - `long utcTime = getUTCDate(new Date())`

Comment: @SrivathsanSrinivasan: No, again you're using string conversions for no reason at all - and your parameter name of `localDate` suggests that you still don't understand what `Date` represents. There's no such thing as a "local" instance of `Date`; it's *always* just an instant of time. This is why I strongly encourage you to use Joda Time or `java.time` in Java 8 - both are much simpler to understand as there are different types for different usages.

Comment: i agree that Date is just a wrapper for sys.currentTimeMillis , but w.o. using string conversion, how can i get the UTC date from the current CST date.can u jus modify the current code and post me, it would be great , thanks

Comment: @SrivathsanSrinivasan: No, I can't just modify the code because it makes no sense. There's no such things as a "UTC date" or a "current CST date" when you're using `long` and `Date`. I think you need to reread all my comments *really carefully* and then if you're still confused, ask a new question with more details about the bigger picture - what you're really trying to achieve. The method you keep posting different forms of makes no sense, so we can only help if you tell us what you're trying to achieve with it... and not in comments here, but in a new question.

Comment: Unix epoch ,is the time difference between current time and 1970 UTC time right , and if i use `syso(new Date())` for new date , its showing the as below , my timezone is CST  - o/p is `Thu Feb 26 03:44:46 CST 2015` , that is why i have used new Date() , even my server is in CST